# Vue.js variables lose scope inside foundation modal

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, zurb-foundation

I have the following `v-for` loop, in the scope of the first opening, and final closing `<div>` tags below.

The first `:src` is able to resolve the file name from the `Vue.js` variables.

The second `:src` (on line 12), is unable to resolve the variables into a string, and the browser instead searches for a file called: `'https://sample.com/' + orderInfo[product].FileName[index]` which does not exist.

Why is the browser unable to interpret/resolve the variable names inside the modal, even though they appear to be in scope of the `v-for` loop.

```
<div v-for="index in orderInfo[product]" :key="index">
    <img :src="'https://sample.com/' + orderInfo[product].FileName[index]"/>

    <div class="file-detail">
        <a data-open="modal"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="reveal large" id="exampleModal1hello" data-reveal>
        <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">Close X</span>
        </button>
        <img :src="'https://sample.com/' + orderInfo[product].FileName[index]"/>
    </div>
</div>
```